# Keep sidebar but remove scrolling JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replicate the way facebook display's pictures in a lightbox type format. The only thing I am having trouble replicating is the way they achieve leaving the sidebar with no actual scroll bar inside...

I guess the best way for anyone to see this is go to facebook pull up a picture so the lightbox effect is in action. Notice the sidebar. Anyone have any suggestions or ways to achieve this? Is there a way to target specific nodes on the scroll bar?

Thanks. jQuery is the library of choice for this project.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly CSS to be honest.

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktd29/11/

I've created the worlds worst lightbox in imitation of what Facebook do. The red square represents the picture and the black, the semi-transparent overlay.

You'll notice that the main body is scrollable until you click the link at which point the scrollbar becomes disabled.

The semi transparent overlay is an absolutely positioned `div` with 100% width and height:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: none;
}
```

The final thing to note about this div is the `overflow-y` is set to `scroll` this will mean there is a scrollbar always present regardless of whether it is actually scrollable or not.

The height of the document is set to something very large so that when you aren't looking at the lightbox the page is scrollable. Here is the code for calling the lightbox:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('div').addClass('shown');
        $('html').addClass('noScroll');
    });
});
```

This is what you'd expect. I am applying a class of shown which in this example is literally just `display: block;` but notice the class of `noScroll` being applied to the HTML. This applies `overflow-y: hidden;` to the html which removes the original scrollbar. This stops there being two scrollbars (one for the html and one for the overlay div).

Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

​